# WebGl faulty calculating of normals

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, webgl

I've been calculating normals for my webgl lightning and I encountered an issue where there is a linear pattern of black spaces, I have smothed it a little by adding 0.1 to every normal but it still looks bad, annyone knows how to solve it?

Function:

```
function initVertexNormals(verts, indices, rowSize, num_dims) {
    //
    const normals = new Array(vertexNormals.length).fill(0);

    // Iterate through the indices to calculate normals

    //for loop size explained:
    //vertexNormals.length/2: we calculate normal for each square not triangle
    // - 3 * rowSize: we can't calculate normals for last row as we need points in next row to make calculations,
    //                so the 2nd last iteration takes care of last row normals.
    for (let i= 0; i < vertexNormals.length/2 - 3 * rowSize; i+=3) {
        const b = [vertices[i], vertices[i + 1], vertices[i + 2]];
        const s = [vertices[(i + rowSize * num_dims)], vertices[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 1], vertices[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 2]];

        let r = new Array(3).fill(0);
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            r = [vertices[(i + 1 * num_dims)], vertices[(i + 1 * num_dims) + 1], vertices[(i + 1 * num_dims) + 2]];
        } else {
            r = [vertices[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims)], vertices[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims) + 1], vertices[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims) + 2]];
        }

        const QR = [r[0] - b[0], r[1] - b[1], r[2] - b[2]];
        const QS = [s[0] - b[0], s[1] - b[1], s[2] - b[2]];

        let normal = new Array(3).fill(0);
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            normal = [(QR[0] * QS[0]) / 2, (QR[1] * QS[1]) / 2, (QR[2] * QS[2]) / 2];

            for (let j= 0; j<num_dims; j++){
                normal[j] = 1/Math.abs(normal[j] - 0.1);
            }

            normals[i] = normal[0];
            normals[i + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[i + 2] = normal[2];

            normals[(i + 1 * num_dims)] = normal[0];
            normals[(i + 1 * num_dims) + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[(i + 1 * num_dims) + 2] = normal[2];

            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims)] = normal[0];
            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 2] = normal[2];
        } else {
            normal = [QR[0] * QS[0], QR[1] * QS[1], QR[2] * QS[2]];

            for (let j= 0; j<num_dims; j++){
                normal[j] = 1/Math.abs(normal[j] - 0.1);
            }

            normals[i] = normal[0];
            normals[i + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[i + 2] = normal[2];

            normals[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims)] = normal[0];
            normals[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims) + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[(i + (rowSize - 1) * num_dims) + 2] = normal[2];

            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims)] = normal[0];
            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 1] = normal[1];
            normals[(i + rowSize * num_dims) + 2] = normal[2];
        }
    }
    return normals;
}
```

part that is the smoother:

```
for (let j= 0; j<num_dims; j++){
    normal[j] = 1/Math.abs(normal[j] - 0.1);
}
```

With smoothing:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDimS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbJ5U.png)

Without smoothing:

[image]

I've also tried to use gl-matrix lib to calculate normals but I had worse results.